# protobuf-net protogen with umbrella classes

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

is there away of getting protobuf-net protogen to wrap an existing proto in an umbrella class.

Similar to in Jon Skeet's proto-csharp implementation:
protogen -namespace=companyx.employee -umbrella_classname=HREmployees -output_directory=. employee.proto

thanks.

Improvement to the question: Essentially if a package is defined in the proto as com.testcompany.protos.employee

we want the ability during generation to place the objects in a sub namespace. eg: 
com.testcompany.protos.employee.testemployee

so messages/objects are then moved into below com.testcompany.protos.employee.testemployee. Of course during re serialization the object should go back to the original: com.testcompany.protos.employee.

The reason for this is that we have many clashing namespace objects between different protos by providing an extra depth we can avoid the clashes.

There may also be another way of doing this but this is how we resolved it when using protobuf-csharp.

thanks.

Comment: *at the moment*, `package` takes precedence, then the `defaultNamespace` parameter, then implicit. However, it should be possible *as a change* to handle some kind of override. To clarify - is it preferable to implement as a *namespace*, or as a *wrapper class*? (with nested types etc)

Comment: Namespace would be perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Just though of another way this could be resolved. If protobuf-net implemented the java equivalent of: option java_outer_classname="HREmployee";

Comment: I will look at that option later (it isn't one I detect at the moment)

Comment: great thanks, In the meantime we have written a simple search and replace script to modify the namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the charp.xslt is editable. I'm happy to consider adding something to the trunk here, but it would need to be clearly stated what you are after - and "umbrella classes" isn't meaning much to me at the moment.

Additionally, since protobuf-net *the library* is based purely on the classes at runtime (the codegen is fairly uninteresting), ou can also manually add any extra classes you need (or use partial classes to extend the generated ones).

So lots of options. If you want something adding to the code, it'll need to be clear on what you mean.